# How to handle methods with different return types if the objects have same base class?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, return-type

I've searched this everywhere, but I haven't found anything that actually helps me.
I have a Method that returns a list of different objects (Either a list of cats or a list of dogs) depending on the argument given:

```
static **What Goes here?** GetAnimalList(char animalType)
        {
            switch (animalType)
            {
                case 'D':
                    return Dog.GetList();

                case 'C':
                    return Cat.GetList();

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error, here goes an exception");
            }
        }
```

Both Dog and Cat inherit from Animal. Both Classes have their own GetList, which generates a List of instances of them.
The Animal Abstract Class has methods that work fine for both types of animal.

Here's the three classes:

```
abstract class Animal
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Owner{ get; set; }
}



class Dog : Animal
{
    public string DogThing { get; set; }
   
    public static IList<Dog> GetList()
    {
        using (IDBConnection con = DBConnection.Instance())
        {
            IList<Dog> dogs= new List<Dog>();

            dogs= con.Connect(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString)
                .Select<Dog>(Properties.Settings.Default.StoredProcedure, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            return dogs;
        }
    }
}


class Cat: Animal
{
    public string CatThing { get; set; }
       
    public static IList<Cat> GetList()
    {
        using (IDBConnection con = DBConnection.Instance())
        {
            IList<Cat> cats= new List<Cat>();

            cats= con.Connect(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString)
                    .Select<Cat>(Properties.Settings.Default.StoredProcedure, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            return cats;
        }
    }
}
```

If I make the return type be IList< Animal > it gives me the error:

> Cannot Implicitly Convert type Systems.Collections.Generic.IList<Animal.Dog> to
> Systems.Collections.Generic.IList<Animal.Animal>

I've tried Casting the returns with (Animal) to no success.

The Point of the code is to later print out either a list of dogs or a list of cats and their info. Ideally I would call the x.ToString(). but I'm stuck ): Is this possible in C#?
I feel like this might be a design issue but I don't know how to go about it.

Comment: [make `IAnimal` interface and use `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VSzr5L)

Comment: Have you tried using object as return type? Simply check the type of object at runtime and cast it to your desired type accordingly.

Comment: A `List<Dog>` is *not* a `List<Animal>`. If you could perform the cast, someone receiving that `List<Animal>` could insert a `Cat` into it - but the actual object is still a `List<Dog>`. You can cast the members and construct a *new* list of an appropriate type.

Comment: @Selvin `IEnumerable<Animal>` should even without extra interface.

Comment: Sadly had already tried Object to no avail.

IEnumerable<Animal> worked for the immediate problem that the method wasn't running, but I ran into different problems later on in the code. 

@Damien_The_Unbeliever That was exactly the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Edit: I've omitted `IList` and just used `List` in this example for the sake of simplicity, but the principle remains the same. You can definitely use `IList` if you prefer.*

### The problem

Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment is correct. Counterintuitively, you cannot just return a `List<Dog>` as if it's a `List<Animal>`. You'd think you could, because you can return `Dog` as `Animal`, but [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) stops you from doing so.

Very basically put, consider this code. Is this valid code?

```
var list = new List<Animal>();

list.Add(new Dog());
```

Yes it is. So how about this?

```
var list = new List<Cat>();

list.Add(new Dog());
```

This is not correct code. A `Dog` does not derive from a `Cat`, and a `List<Cat>` can only receive `Cat` objects (or derivations).

How about this?

```
List<Animal> list = GetAnimals();

list.Add(new Dog());

private List<Animal> GetAnimals() 
{
     return new List<Animal>();
}
```

This is valid. But what about this?

```
List<Animal> list = GetAnimals();

list.Add(new Dog());

private List<Animal> GetAnimals() 
{
     return new List<Cat>();
}
```

This breaks, for the same reason that the second example breaks. A `Dog` does not derive from a `Cat`, and a `List<Cat>` can only receive `Cat` objects (or derivations).

This is why you can't just rely on implicit downcasting of your generic types, and why you can't return a `List<Cat>` as if it's a `List<Animal>`. It actually loosens the type constraint (instead of only being able to add `Cat` objects, now you can add *any* `Animal`), which violates the object as it is.

---

### The solution

What you need to do here is add the dogs or cats to a `List<Animal>` instead of adding them to a `List<Dog>` or `List<Cat>`. Then you are able to return that `List<Animal>`

There's a few ways of doing this.

Adding it to an explicitly instantiated list:

```
public List<Animal> GetAnimalList(char animalType)
{
    var list = new List<Animal>();

    switch (animalType)
    {
        case 'D':
            list.AddRange(Dog.GetList());

        case 'C':
            list.AddRange(Cat.GetList());

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error, here goes an exception");
    }

    return list;
}
```

Using LINQ:

```
public List<Animal> GetAnimalList(char animalType)
{
    switch (animalType)
    {
        case 'D':
            return Dog.GetList().Cast<Animal>().ToList();

        case 'C':
            return Cat.GetList().Cast<Animal>().ToList();

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error, here goes an exception");
    }
}
```

Other ways exist, but it always boils down to the same thing: add your `Cat`/`Dog` objects to a `List<>` whose generic type is `Animal`, not `Cat` or `Dog`.

Comment: Great Answer! I ended up using the explicitly instantiated list. This is my first time posting a question in StackOverflow and I'm pleasantly surprised at how quick the answers rolled in :) Eternally grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [generics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/generics); wrote you a sample program without the connection related things:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach (var item in GetAnimalList<Dog>('D'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.DogThing);
            }
        }

        static List<T> GetAnimalList<T>(char animalType)
        {
            switch (animalType)
            {
                case 'D':
                    return Dog.GetList().Cast<T>().ToList();
                case 'C':
                    return Cat.GetList().Cast<T>().ToList();
                default:
                    throw new Exception("unsupported type");
            }
        }

    }
    abstract class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public string DogThing { get; set; }

        public static IList<Dog> GetList()
        {
            IList<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>() { new Dog() { DogThing = "bowwow" }, new Dog() { DogThing = "wow?" } };
            return dogs;
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public string CatThing { get; set; }

        public static IList<Cat> GetList()
        {
            IList<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>() { new Cat() { CatThing = "Meow" },new Cat() { CatThing = "Meowy" } };
            return cats;
        }
    }
}
```

Exemplified version :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var animal = new Animal<Dog>() { Name = "Sparky", Owner = "John Doe" };

            Console.WriteLine($"{animal.Name} belongs to {animal.Owner}");
            Console.WriteLine($"{animal.Name} loves to {animal.GetList().First().DogThing} or {animal.GetList().Last().DogThing}");
        }
    }

    interface IAnimals<T>
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        string Owner { get; set; }
        IList<T> GetList();
    }

    class Animal<T> : IAnimals<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Owner { get; set; }

        public IList<T> GetList()
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(Dog))
            {
                //intialize db connection[Not recommended] | call a service with your data[Better approach]
                IList<Dog> dogs = new List<Dog>() { new Dog() { DogThing = "Eat" }, new Dog() { DogThing = "Chew on rug" } };
                return dogs.Cast<T>().ToList();
            }
            else if (typeof(T) == typeof(Cat))
            {
                //intialize db connection[Not recommended] | call a service with your data[Better approach]
                IList<Cat> cats = new List<Cat>() { new Cat() { CatThing = "Hiss" }, new Cat() { CatThing = "Eat fish" } };
                return cats as List<T>;
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception("unsupported type");
            }
        }
    }

    class Dog
    {
        public string DogThing { get; set; }
    }

    class Cat
    {
        public string CatThing { get; set; }
    }    
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image]

Your original approach is not optimal which is why you can see people on this thread recommending several ways and patterns to make it better.

Comment: Generics make no sense here. The caller has no idea which subtype of `Animal` they will receive, because  `GetAnimalList` is the one who decides what kind of animals to return (based on the passed character). The only sensical type to use for `T` is `Animal`, not `Cat` or `Dog`, so the generic parameter falls flat.

Comment: @Flater why not ? OP says ` I have a Method that returns a list of different objects (Either a list of cats or a list of dogs) depending on the argument given` , I understand that animal is base for both cat and dog but OP clearly wants a list of cat or dog based on a literal and not type Animal.

Comment: They make more sense if you remove the char parameter from GetAnimalList<T> and just get the type of T and then cast it as the concrete type

Comment: @Manti_Core: The caller supplies a char value. The method _internally_ decides what kind of animal will be returned based on that character. The caller has no idea what the outcome of the decision will be, otherwise it'd be a massive violation of encapsulation. To put it differently, if you use your approach of input value on switch and generic parameter to decide the output type that is already fixed based on the input value, then you could've really just created some much simpler `GetDogs` and `GetCats` methods. Having `GetAnimals` proves that the caller doesn't know what animal to expect.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you have here is something that can be explained with Covariance and Contravariance (see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) for more information).

Assume your example where you have a `List<Dog>`, if you cast/convert it to `List<Animal>`, then that means that you now have the option to call `animalList.Add(new Cat())`, and this will fail because a cat is not a dog. To solve this you need to go to a type that doesn't accept any instance of your class but only outputs the type `Animal`.

If we look at the type of [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) we see that it inherits from some classes, we are only interested in the generic versions. If we look further we see for example [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1). This last one (`IEnumerable<T>`) is declared as

```cs
public interface IEnumerable<out T>
```

while the `ICollection<T>` doesn't mention that 'out' keyword. This keyword is telling that the `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant and thus will only output your type and doesn't allow input of it. In turn this makes it safe to cast your list to.

Another option is [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1) which will provide you with a `Count` property and the option to get an element at a specific index.

If you really want to use a `List<T>`, then your only option is to create a new list, copy everything over and return that. This has the consequence that you can add a dog to a list that was only meant for cats. You can do this as follows:

```cs
return Dog.GetList().ToList<Animal>();
```

or

```cs
return new List<Animal>(Dog.GetList());
```

I hope that this helps and clears up your question.